# MVC5 textarea rows cols work only when specified explicitly and not via htmlAttributes

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, 20, 50, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })`

**Question**: The above code displays rows and cols of textarea correctly but the below ignores rows/cols and displays the default size per browser. What's wrong in below code?

The extra `new` in below code was auto created by VS when creating a MVC Entity Framework controller (as documented at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes)

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @rows="20", @cols="50"} })`

Answer (score 6):

This works on MVC 5.2.2:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Caracteristicas, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "10" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using mvc5 cols and rows attribute for TextAreaFor, and also apply the CSS style for the text area.

```
        <div class="col-md-10" id="textArea">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, 10, 100, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                
        </div>
```

And CSS:

```
#textArea textarea {
max-width: 600px;}
```

Comment: This worked for me:    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WorkDetails, 10, 94, new { @class = "form-control" })

Answer (score 1):

In ASP MVC5 you can use `col-[size]-[width]` instead of `@col="50"` for textarea or textbox controls. If you want something wider than "12" then use style.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.DESCRIPTION, new { @class = "form-control col-md-12", rows="20" })
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done you will have to use the same syntax you would use for @Html.EditorFor

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", rows=20, cols=50 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, 20, 50, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

For This

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, 20, 50, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",@rows="6" })
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer it will improve your answer quality

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe that the extra **new** is necessary you should just be able to do:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, new { @class = "form-control", @rows="20", @cols="50" })
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm trying to understand _why_ it's not working when it's both documented and created by Microsoft.

Comment: I believe that the documentation is specific to the EditorFor Html helper.  I don't believe that the individual "Control" helpers were meant to use that syntax if I am understanding the documentation in the provided link.